# How can I record time now in RichTextBox in WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, multithreading, user-interface

Here is my codes,the main xaml.cs file:

```
//using statements...

namespace WpfAppTestRichTextBox
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Start();
        }

        // Initialize the richTextBox...
        public void Start()
        {
            Run r = new Run("");
            p.Inlines.Add(r);
            richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
        }

        // Button Click and Start a new Thread to record time for each second.
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread th = new System.Threading.Thread(ChangeText);
            th.Start();
        }

        public void ChangeText()
        {
           while(true)
           {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {

                    string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
                    Run r = new Run(time);
                    p.Inlines.Add(r);

                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I add the new Run() to the Paragraph and expect the content of the richTextBox will be refreshed.But it blocks in while() and print nothing in richTextBox.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have your sleep inside the dispatcher thread. Did you intend to place it after the dispatcher invoke?

```
while(true)
{
    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        Run r = new Run(time);
        p.Inlines.Add(r);
    }));
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

[Thread.Sleep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.sleep?view=netframework-4.8)

> Suspends the current thread for the specified amount of time.

Dispatcher.Invoke dispatches the code inside the block to run on the UI thread. Putting the sleep in there Suspends the UI thread essentially causing it to freeze up.

UPDATE: A better solution would be to use a dispatcher timer.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    public Paragraph p = new Paragraph();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
    }


    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string time = System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\n";
        Run r = new Run(time);
        p.Inlines.Add(r);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Run r = new Run("");
        p.Inlines.Add(r);
        richTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me!But I thought it just sleeps 1000 ms .Why the Sleep() statement can blocks the UI Thread?

Comment: I've added more details to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, changing your method to async would be a good idea, but to answer your question, it is possible that your UI is just not refreshing due to the method never ending or giving control back to the caller. Try forcing a refresh:

```
 if (richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
 {
      richTextBox.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
      {
          richTextBox.Refresh();

       }));
 }
 else richTextBox.Refresh();
 Application.DoEvents();
```

If that doesn't work then try doing things like running in debug mode and checking the value of p at certain times, or try altering the value of the textbox.Text directly to see where your actual bug is